# How can I find the closest points of two finite sets in 3D?

Tags: algorithm, 3d

I have two finite sets A and B of points in 3D.
I want to know if the convex hulls intersect, and if not, I want compute a pair of points (a,b) with a in A and b in B such that the distance d(a,b) takes the minimum min { d(a,b) | a in A, b in B}.

What algorithms are there other than testing each pair of points by brute force?

Comment: [Gilbert–Johnson–Keerthi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Keerthi_distance_algorithm)?

Comment: That looks like a good start, thanks. I don't understand that "NearestSimplex(s)" yet and I'm not sure if this gives me a pair of nearest points or only the resulting distance.  I'll look into that.

Comment: Intuitively, draw the shortest line segment possible from the origin to some point in the simplex `s` (point, line segment, triangle, or tetrahedron). The boundary of a simplex consists of simplices having dimension one smaller; NearestSimplex should return the boundary simplex that the line segment from the origin lands on.

Comment: so dim(NearestSimplex(s))=dim(s)-1 ? And the basic idea of teh algorithm is to break down the convex sets into simpices?

Comment: Hm, judging by the pseudocode, I think it should be dim(NearestSimplex(s))=min(dim(s),3), actually. I've never implemented GJK, so perhaps digging up some tutorial material would be more useful than asking me questions.

Comment: Agreed. And a google search for Gilbert–Johnson–Keerthi is much more promising than a search for "set" and "points". Thanks.

Comment: There is an implementation of GJK in Jinngine, isn't it? https://code.google.com/p/jinngine/source/browse/trunk/jinngine/src/jinngine/collision/GJK.java